# showing the limit of a recurrence relation

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

The recurrence relation is defined as such:

$$a_n=2+\frac{80}{a_{n-1}}$$

It is also given that $a_1=2$, how do we show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=10 ?$$

I am totally stuck at how I should approach this question.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion!

Comment: Say $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$. What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It can be either -8 or 10? How do we show it has to be 10?

Comment: You can show by induction that the terms of the sequence are bigger than 2, and so the limit must be greater or equal to 2. you still have to prove that the sequence converges!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Thanks for your thanks. Now. Supposing that $\lim a_n=L$, what is $\lim a_{n-1}$? (Meant to ask that the first time, didn't read the question carefully)

Answer (score 4):

It can be shown easily by mathematical induction that (cf. Mr. Scott's answer) the subsequence $\{a_{2n}\}_{n \geq 1}$ is decreasing and bounded below by $10$, whereas the subsequence $\{a_{2n - 1}\}_{n \geq 1}$ is increasing and bounded above by $10$, hence by monotone bounded convergence theorem, each subsequence converges, denote their limits by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively, which are all strictly greater than $0$. On one hand, let $n \to \infty$ in 
$$a_{2n + 1} = 2 + \frac{80}{a_{2n}}$$
to get 
$$\beta = 2 + \frac{80}{\alpha}.\tag{1}$$
On the other hand, let $n \to \infty$ in 
$$a_{2n + 2} = 2 + \frac{80}{a_{2n + 1}}$$
to get 
$$\alpha = 2 + \frac{80}{\beta}. \tag{2}$$
Solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ for $\alpha, \beta$, we have (the negative roots are discarded)
$$\alpha = \beta = 10.$$
showing that $\{a_n\}$ converges (using the well-known proposition that a sequence converges if and only if its odd-subsequence and even-subsequence converge to the same value), and the limit is $10$.

P.S. In response to David C. Ullrich's concern (it's a very good one, we should not leave out any nontrivial details), I will add the details showing $\{a_{2n}\}$ and $\{a_{2n - 1}\}$ are monotonic. The bounded part has already been shown in Mr.Scott's answer.

For $n = 1$, $a_1 = 2, a_2 = 2 + 80/2 = 42, a_3 = 2 + 80/43 > 2, a_4 < 2 + 80/2 = 42 = a_2$. The initial steps have been checked.

Assume for $n = k > 1$, we have $a_{2k} < a_{2k - 2}, a_{2k + 1} > a_{2k - 1}$. Then for $n = k + 1$, 
$$a_{2k + 2} - a_{2k} = (2 + 80/a_{2k + 1}) - (2 + 80/a_{2k - 1}) = 80(1/a_{2k + 1} - 1/a_{2k - 1}) < 0$$
by induction assumption, and
$$a_{2k + 3} - a_{2k + 1} = (2 + 80/a_{2k + 2}) - (2 + 80/a_{2k}) = 80(1/a_{2k + 2} - 1/a_{2k}) > 0$$ 
by above inequality just proved. Hence the induction step is completed.

Comment: I like this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the recurrence

$$a_n=2+\frac{80}{a_{n-1}}$$

to show that if $a_{n-1}<10$, then $a_n>10$, while if $a_{n-1}>10$, then $a_n<10$. Since $a_1=2<10$, we have $a_n<10$ when $n$ is odd, and $a_n>10$ when $n$ is even. Now

$$\begin{align*}
|a_n-10|&=\left|\frac{80}{a_{n-1}}-8\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{80-8a_{n-1}}{a_{n-1}}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{8(10-a_{n-1})}{a_{n-1}}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac8{a_{n-1}}\right|\cdot|a_{n-1}-10|\;,
\end{align*}$$

so $|a_n-10|<|a_{n-1}-10|$ provided that $a_{n-1}>8$. Suppose that you can find an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $8<a_m<10$.

- Show that $a_n>8$ for all $n\ge m$.
- Let $r=\frac8{a_m}$, and show by induction on $k$ that $$|a_{m+k}-10|\le r^k|a_m-10|$$ for all $k\ge 0$. Do you see why that implies the desired result?

All that’s needed now is to find such an $m$; it’s a little tedious, but you can do it by direct calculation; the smallest such $m$ is less than $15$.

Comment: Did you get the $m$ by direct computation on a computer? Do you guarantee the accuracy by interval arithmetic using the machine precision of your computer?

Comment: @Hans: Integer arithmetic by hand; the numbers are all rational, after all.

Comment: Haha, right in this case. What do we do with $2\rightarrow \sqrt{4+0.01}$ and $80\rightarrow 80+\sqrt{0.01}$?

Comment: I like your answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

What Zhanxiong wrote looks simpler, but it looks like maybe it just looks simpler because he left out some details. Someone should point out that no, looking at it that way makes the details simpler as well.

The recurrence shows that $$a_{n+2}-10=\frac{32}{40+a_n}(a_n-10).$$
So all we have to show is that $a_n>0$ and we know that the numbers $a_{2n}-10$ all have the same sign and decrease geometrically in absolute value; similarly for $a_{2n+1}$.