# Showing that the sequence $ x_n = \frac {1}{1 + x_{n-1}} $ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Sequence is recursively defined by $ x_0 = 1 $

I managed to show it is boundness by showing that $ 0 \lt x_n \lt 1 $

Now, when i try to show monotony of the sequence i got the problem because sequence is neither increasing or decreasing. 
I don't know what to do here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Try to show that $\{x_{2n}\}$ is monotonically increasing while $\{x_{2n + 1}\}$ is monotonically decreasing, and they converge to the same limit.

For a similar problem and the complete answer, check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342829/showing-the-limit-of-a-recurrence-relation/1342889#1342889) post.

Comment: Hmm I tried, but it seems that i come everytime in contradiction.Don't know why. Probably i'm doing something wrong. Any additional hints?

Comment: I added another hint which gives a very similar problem to your question, please read it then try more.

Comment: Thanks. It's actually what i needed to see although the proof by David it's quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  Often the easiest way to do this sort of problem is to find the limit **if it exists**, then prove that that limit actually is correct.

In this case it is clear that the limit, if it exists, is positive and satisfies
$$L=\frac1{1+L}\ ,$$
so $L^2+L-1=0$ and hence
$$L=\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}\ .$$
Now we have
$$\left|x_n-L\right|=\Bigl|\frac1{1+x_{n-1}}-L\Bigr|
  =\Bigl|\frac{1-L-Lx_{n-1}}{1+x_{n-1}}\Bigr|\ ;$$
replacing $1-L$ by $L^2$ and doing a bit of algebra,
$$\left|x_n-L\right|=\Bigl(\frac{L}{1+x_{n-1}}\Bigr)\left|x_{n-1}-L\right|\ .$$
Since $0<L<1$ and $1+x_{n-1}>1$ we have $\left|x_n-L\right|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, and this completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you. Helped me develop a new idea approaching recurrence sequences.